# Linq select with where query logical error

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, linq, c#-4.0

I'm getting the logical errors which are printing out the same results in stead of the unique records

This is my code:

```
public List<castName> getCharactersById(int moveId)
   {
       var tCast = db.GetTable<castName>();

       var query = tCast.Where(m => (m.Id == moveId)).Distinct();

       var list = new List<castName>(query);

       return list;
    }
```

castName class

```
[Table]
public class castName
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string castname { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string castrole { get; set; }

}
```

**linq query results errors**
http://i60.tinypic.com/svnkmo.png

**it should print this result**
http://i59.tinypic.com/10z4e8y.png

Comment: What is the `GetTable<>` method? What is your LINQ provider? Entity Framework? LINQ to Entities? Can you output the SQL that is being produced for your query?

Comment: Please show the class definition for castName. How do you compare for equality?

Comment: @andyp - comparison is done through linq query

Comment: Why not just Distinct().ToList()?

Comment: Distinct() uses the default equality comparer, so I'd guess your duplicate castName instances aren't equal. See the last paragraphs of the remarks section: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx